# Freeform Pro: nested if statement

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm using Freeform Pro 4.0.12.

Does exp:freeform:entries allow for nested if statements, like below?

```
{if freeform:field:yes_no_002 == "Y"}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Person 2:</td>
    </tr>

    {if freeform:field:r_type_of_presentation == "Roundtable"}
        <tr>
             <td>Are you a moderator or Discussionist?</td>
             <td>{freeform:field:r_round_table_leaders_002}</td>
        </tr>
    {/if}
{/if}
```

I haven't been able to get this to work.

Thanks

Peter T

Answer (score 1):

Freeform uses the default EE template parser so however conditionals are parsed normally should work the same in FFP.

However the EE template parser sometimes has quirks with conditionals. Have you tried making the variables in quotes?

```
 {if "{freeform:field:r_type_of_presentation}" == "Roundtable"}
```